# Several SignalR calls makes the UI not responding

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-interface, signalr

We do have this Execute method of a task scheduler application and it processes the output string received buy a Process (System.Diagnostics):

```
    public override void Execute()
    {
        // ... more logic above 

        Process = new Process { StartInfo = { FileName = fileName, Arguments = args } };
        Process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        Process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        Process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        Process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        Process.Exited += ProcessExited;
        Process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(
                delegate(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
                {
                    if (e.Data != null)
                    {
                        lock (ExecutionContext)
                        {
                            ExecutionContext.AppendOutput(e.Data);
                        }
                    }
                }
            );

        Process.Start();
        Process.BeginOutputReadLine();
    }


    public void AppendOutput(string str)
    {
        // To do: Append strings to the _currentOutput within a period of time
        _currentOutput += str + Environment.NewLine;

        // Before doing the following
        SendOutput(_currentOutput);

        // Reset the variable
        _currentOutput = "";
    }
```

The SendOutput method sends the output to the UI via SignalR.

The problem is when the Process runs a command that produces several outputs, it also makes several SignalR calls to the UI that makes it locked up.

First, I solved the UI issue by using the setTimeout Javascript method. It does not lock up anymore but it prolongs the display of the output because of the series of timeouts.

I think the best way to handle these outputs is through server-side by concatenating a series of outputs within a period of time, lets say for 1 to 2 seconds, before sending them to the UI. I am leaning towards using a Timer or Task.Delay but I cannot construct it clearly.

Hope someone helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A timer should sort this for you. Here's some code that will do this (a hack as I've not got your base class). This runs in a console so obviously you will have to do some work like removing calls to the console. The calls are there so you can test this in a console app. The SendOutput method here just writes to the console, but you'd just delete that and it should call out to your signalR client.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Timers;

namespace bufferOutput
{
    public class Processor
    {
        private object bufferLock = new object();
        private StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        private Timer updateTime = new Timer(250);//fire every quarter second: a reasonable time for a web page to update

        public void Execute(string fileName, string args)
        {
            var process = new Process { StartInfo = { FileName = fileName, Arguments = args } };
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            process.Exited += ProcessExited;
            process.OutputDataReceived += AppendOutput;
            process.Start();
            updateTime.Elapsed += updateTime_Elapsed;
            process.BeginOutputReadLine();
            updateTime.Start();
            Console.Title = "Buffered data: Press the Enter key to exit the program.";
            Console.ReadLine();
            ProcessExited(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        void updateTime_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            string output = "";
            lock(bufferLock)
            {
                output = sb.ToString();
                if (output != "")//if there was anything in the strng builder, clear it
                    sb = new StringBuilder();
            }
            if (output != "")
                SendOutput(output);
        }

        public void ProcessExited(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            updateTime.Stop();
            Console.Title = "writing out buffer: Press the Enter key to exit the program.";
            updateTime_Elapsed(this, null);
            SendOutput("Done");
        }

        public void AppendOutput(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Data != null)
            {
                lock (bufferLock)
                    sb.AppendLine(e.Data);
            }
        }

        public void SendOutput(string output)//placeholder for the client side
        {
            Console.WriteLine(output);
        }
    }
}
```

It looks like you're locking your class in the output data received event handler of the process which is probably not the best idea.

Comment: Thanks for your effort Kell. I am now using a Timer but I am still checking your example to compare. May I know why the current lock in my code is not a good thing?

Comment: It looks like your class is called ExecutionContext so you're effectively locking the type. If it's a public type this can be a problem as anything can take a lock on it and cause deadlocks. You typically want to lock on a private object within the thread-safe class to prevent this kind of deadlocks

Comment: I use StopWatch instead but the logic is the same. Thanks again Kell.